# Browser application bundle generation complete. Copying assets complete. Index html generation failed. ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\

Tags: angular, node-modules, ng

To solve this issue, you need to delete the .cache folder from node_modules.

This error occurs when running:
ng build --prod --base-href /CitrinoV4/

✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✖ Index html generation failed.
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\AAFILEMON\CITRINOV4\AngularCitrino-Angular12\node_modules.cache\